# Javascript multiple replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How do you replace all instances of one string with another in javascript?
Example:

```
someString = 'the cat looks like a cat'
anotherString = someString.replace('cat', 'dog');
```

results in anotherString being set to 'the **dog** looks like a **cat**', and I would like it to be 'the **dog** looks like a **dog**'