# Changing multiple strings in one line of code

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace several words in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784595/how-to-replace-several-words-in-javascript)

I have a string:

```
var str = "1000 g teerts smarg 700 vickenbauer 400";
```

I need to replace `teerts`, `vickenbauer` by white spaces.

I can do like:

```
str.replace("teerts", "");
str.replace("vickenbauer", "");
```

But, is there any way to bind the two into just one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RegExp with replace

```
str.replace(/(teerts|vickenbauer)/g, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the replaces:

```
str = str.replace("teerts","").replace("vickenbauer","");
```

Note that the `replace` method doesn't change the string that you use it on, you have to take care of the return value.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Sure!](http://jsfiddle.net/pvd4v/)

```
"1000 g teerts smarg 700 vickenbauer 400".replace(/teerts|vickenbauer/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex?

```
str.replace(/(teerts|vickenbauer)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(new RegExp(/teerts|vickenbauer/g), "");
```