# Replace a string between particular characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a problem to add the dynamic values to a string.

For example:

```
My name is < NAME >
```

Now I want to replace `NAME` with my name so my string will become:

```
My name is anything.
```

How I can achieve this?

The dynamic part will be always between `<>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = "My name is < NAME >".replace("< NAME >", "anything");
```

do you want this? Or are you searching for something more complex that enums all the words between `< and >`? Something like:

```
var matches = "My name is < NAME > < SURNAME >".match(/<[^>]+>/g);
```

If you want to replace multiple parts you could do this:

```
var replacer = function (str)  
{  
    if (str === '< NAME >')
    {
        return 'anything';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'nothing';
    }
};

var replaced = 'My name is < NAME > < SURNAME >'.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, replacer));
```

Test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rZuNX/

A more complete example:

```
var name = 'anything';
var surname = 'anyone';

var myInputText = "My name is < NAME > < SURNAME >";

var replaced = myInputText
    .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, 
        function (str)  
        {  
            if (str === '< NAME >')
            {
                return name;
            }
            else if (str === '< SURNAME >')
            {
                return surname;
            }
            else
            {
                return '***error***';
            }
        }
    );
```

I'm using javascript anonymous functions that "close" around the `name` and `surname` variables.

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rZuNX/1/

Comment: Thanks for reply
I want that anything between "< >" should be replaced by another value that I will give. It may be name, city etc..
Also string is not known to me except I know that I should replace the text between "<>" that is it.

Comment: @adn295 See the last example for multiple matches. You can save the values in the "name" "surname" variables.

Comment: @adn295 Changed the example (the last one). Like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "My name is < NAME >";
 str = str.replace("NAME", "anything");
```

Answer (score 0):

`/< NAME >/.replace("My name is < NAME >", "anything")` is the basic form for a regualr expression, obviously you can then begin to manipulate the regexp to match other things. W3Schools is a good starting point on [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) in Javascript, and this [online tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) is very good.

Answer (score -1):

```
"I have <name>".replace(/<name>/, 'Any Thing')
```

results in `I have Any Thing`

Comment: Thanks for reply...
But there may be anything instead of name.
It should also be replicable. How to do that ???

Comment: please, look at that link in comment below the question. For multiple replaces use /g modifier, and just loop through your subsitutions and do the thing in a loop. Of course, that will be better to wrap functionality into class.