# Javascript Replace function skipping a match

Tags: javascript, replace

The second 'senzajs' in the `<map>` is not being replaced but I would like it to...

Javascript

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
     $('body').html($('body').html().replace('senzajs', 'js'));
   });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="objectdiv">
   <a href="freegames/Classic/svgsenzajs/start.php/">
    <object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml"  data="svg/question0optimize1.svg" >
         <img src="png/question0optimize1.png" type="image/png" usemap="#mapping"/>    
     </object>   
   </a>
   <map name="mapping">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,1000,1000" 
         href="freegames/Classic/pngsenzajs/start.php/" />
    </map>
 </div>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.replace(/senzajs/g, 'js')`. A regex with the `g` flag will match all occurrences instead of just the first one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex here otherwise replace only replace the first string found. /senzajs/g will match all found one, with exactly the same case. Add i to ignore the casing /senzajs/gi so even SENZJAS would be replaced.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
     $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/senzajs/g, 'js'));
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The replace function as you've used it only replaces the first instance it finds. Use a regular expression to replace all instances:

```
var myNewString = myOldString.replace(/username/g, visitorName);
```

(I lifted this from http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
     $('body').html($('body').html().replace('/senzajs/gm', 'js'));
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: `m` is not really necessary as he's not using `^` or `$`