# How to replace all the \ from a string with space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

For example:

```
 var str="abc\'defgh\'123";
```

I want to remove all the `\` using Javascript. I have tried with several functions but still can't replace all the forward slashes.

Comment: *"I have tried with several functions"* .. you should also include what you have tried so others can help you understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted a *huuuge* load of bollocks on JS and [multiple replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace/9514142#9514142) functionality here. But in your case any of the following ways will do nicely:

```
str = str.replace('\\',' ');//Only replaces first occurrence 
str = str.replace(/\\/g,' ');
str = str.split('\\').join(' ');
```

As @Guillaume Poussel pointed out, the first approach only replaces one occurrence of the backslash. Don't use that one, either use the regex, or (if your string is quite long) use the `split().join()` approach.

Comment: The first one will only replace the first backslash though.

Comment: You're right. I tried `'foo\' bar\' foo'.replace('\\',' ')` in the console, forgetting that the one slash just escaped the quote. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use the replace function like this:

```
str = str.replace('\\', ' ');
```

Careful, you need to escape `\` with another `\`. The function returns the modified string, it doesn't modify the string on which it is called, so you need to catch the return value like in my example! So just doing:

```
str.replace('\\', ' ');
```

And then using `str`, will work with the original string, without the replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)

In your case:

```
str.replace('\\', ' ');
```

Comment: Your JS code is invalid (missing `\ `) + it will only replace the first `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

```
str="abc\\'asdf\\asdf"
str=str.replace(/\\/g,' ')
```

You want to replace **all** `'\'` in your case, however, the function replace will only do replacing once if you use '\' directly. You have to write the pattern as a regular expression.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Using string.replace:

```
var result = str.replace('\\', ' ');
```

Result:

```
"abc 'defgh '123"
```