# How do I spilt a string in JavaScript by using a WORD as a delimiter?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, delimiter

Thanks for looking!

Using JavaScript, how do I split a string using a whole word as the delimiter?  Example:

```
var myString = "Apples foo Bananas foo Grapes foo Oranges";
var myArray = myString.split(" foo ");

//myArray now equals ["Apples","Bananas","Grapes","Oranges"].
```

Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

Terribly sorry all, I had an unrelated error that was preventing this from working before.  How do I close this question??

Comment: You just did it.

Comment: delete button under the tags?

Comment: OK, two more votes to close needed please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

… just like you've shown?

```
> "Apples foo Bananas foo Grapes foo Oranges".split(" foo ")
["Apples", "Bananas", "Grapes", "Oranges"]
```

You could also use a regular expression as the delimiter:

```
> "Apples foo Bananas foo Grapes foo Oranges".split(/ *foo */)
["Apples", "Bananas", "Grapes", "Oranges"]
```

Comment: I must be missing something, I tried it my way and got an error.  I'll try again. . .

Comment: My apologies, I had an unrelated error that prevented it from working earlier.  Can you please help close the question?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If it can only be a delimiter if it's a *full* word (berries, but not blackberries), you can use *word boundaries* in a regular expression:

```
var arr = fruityString.split(/\bfoo\b/);
```

Note that dashes (`-`) are also considered word-boundaries, but you can adapt your expression so it *doesn't* split on dashes either: use [the regex I provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace/9514142#9514142) for that