# How to be more restrictive on a split?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to be more restrictive with my `split` by only take the string that is given. I mean it should replace only the string that is given, not the one with `_dyna`.

I don't know how to convert my split to resolve that.

My wish is **respect caps and only if the string is the same as the given one**

I think it's only possible to respect caps but maybe someone here know how to do all I want to do

```js
var base = "depends_on: - tomato-app - guacamole_dyna - GUACAMOLE - guacamole - guAcamole"

var newStr = base.split("guacamole").join("newstring");

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: `base.split(/\bguacamole\b/).join("newstring")`? - `\b` matches word boundaries. Alternatively you could match whitespace.

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: @le_m yes it works like that

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465610/how-do-i-spilt-a-string-in-javascript-by-using-a-word-as-a-delimiter/12465717

Comment: wha not use replace instead?

Comment: @NinaScholz because I founded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript but if you have a better solution I'd love to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression which uses whitespace or stast or end of the string. Then replace only the second match.

```js
var base = "depends_on: - tomato-app - guacamole_dyna - GUACAMOLE - guacamole - guAcamole",
    search = 'guacamole',
    replace = 'newstring',
    regex = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + search + '(?=\\s|$)', 'g'),
    newStr = base.replace(regex, '$1' + replace);
    
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: can I put a variable instead of  typing `guacamole` ? Because I tried like this : `replace('/(^|\s)' + myVar + '(?=\s|$)/g', "$1newstring");`  but it doesn't work

Comment: @Jerome, yes, you can build a new regular expression out of a string with the constructor of `RegExp`.

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thank you so much for the nice input (and it's not the first time that you help me with a great input)