# Capturing everything in a string with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

So I have a string that will have basically any kind of text in it and I want to capture all the text with regular expression and replace it.

```
var img_url = "http://grfx.domain.com/photos/dir/school/dir/m-dir/auto_original/123456.jpeg?123456";
img_url.replace(/regexp/,newvalue);
```

Just trying to capture everything in the img_url var and replace it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean. do you want to overwrite the contents with a new string or just replace part of it

Comment: [Learn these first.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) Then if you think you still want to do what you have just written using a regex use this `/^.*$/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want to replace everything, you don't need regex. Simply write:

```
 img_url = newvalue;
```

If you are really determined to do this with a regular expression, this could help:

```
 img_url = img_url.replace(/.*/, newvalue);
```

Comment: Oh, I lolled.  This, OP.  This.

Comment: +1 for the assignment suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks, all solutions worked, but I ended up going with .innerHTML to write what I needed in html instead of replacing it with an image.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reassigning, just use `=`
If you want to replace all matches in one go, use the `g` flag, in which case this question is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace/9514142#9514142)

If that expression needs to be *dynamic*:

```
var expr = new RegExp(replaceVar,'gi');//globally, and case-insensitively
var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(expr,replacement);
```

Note that, here, all back-slashes like you'd use for `\b` have to be escaped, too: `\\b` and `\\/` for forward slashes. *and* `\\\\` for an escaped backslash