# How to substitute a sequence of carriage returns/line breaks by one line break using JavaScript replace?

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

Using the jQuery text function I received a string that contains a lot of carriage returns/line breaks in sequence.

For example, “\r\n \r\n \r\n Welcome Bob\r\n\t \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n Recommendation: Hellot\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n” .

Is it possible to have just one line break instead of a sequence using JavaScript, presumably replace function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
str.replace(/\s*?[\r\n]\s*/g, "\n");
```

to match any whitespaces around your carriage returns/linebreaks and replace them by `\n` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript replace function only replaces the first match. You'll have to use a regular expression to achieve what you want.

`str.replace(/(\r\n[ \t]*)+/g, "\r\n");`

A more extensive SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace).

For the regex: `(\r\n[ \t]*)+`:

```
(         # start group
\r\n      # match your newlines
[ \t]*    # match zero or more spaces and tabs
)         # end group
+         # match all the above once or more times
```