# Javascript replace words from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this text in javascript:

```
'This is a %{component} with a %{value}'
```

I should replace all words that look like `%{\w+}` with `<span>word</span>`

The final result should look like:

```
'This is a <span>component</span> with a <span>value</span>'
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace

Comment: i tried on ruby side, but i realized there are other html tags in the text that should not look like html content, just like plain text,so i decided to do this in javascript side.
return value.split("\s").collect{|w|w.match(/%{(\w+)}/) ? "<span class='badge badge-info'>#{w}</span>" : w }.join(" ")

Comment: If you already know regex this is all you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written use `String.replace` and a RegEx:

```
var originalString = 'This is a %{component} with a %{value}';
var replacedString = originalString.replace(/%\{(\w+)\}/g, '<span>$1</span>');
// "This is a <span>component</span> with a <span>value</span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo">This is a %{component} with a %{value}</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction()
     {
        var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
        var n=str.replace("%{","< span >").replace("}","< /span >");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
     }
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: not exactly.. because there can be another strings like:
"what's up {here}" that will became => 'what's up {here</span>'

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **regex** in javascript / jquery.
Have a look here: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/regexp.htm