# javascript replace() is not replacing all the characters match

Tags: javascript

I want to turn **/Admin/ListOfMovies** into **_Admin_ListOfMovies** using **replace()**.

```
var $id = id.replace('/', '_');
```

It looks like it only replacing the first /. How do I replace all of them?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Comment: I repeatedly found that the default behavior of "replace" is almost useless and dangerous. Why would I want to replace the first occurrence only (in a general case) ? why not the second or third or last ? this method is a major bug creator because of it's very unexpected behavior. I would recommend creating a method with another name in String.prototype that uses the regex version suggested by Matt and start using it everywhere in your team.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [the `g` flag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)

```
var $id = id.replace(/\//g, '_');
```

Comment: dash killer --> stringWithDashes.replace(/-/g, '');

Comment: @beauXjames I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: just sharing the reason d'etre for me even being here...I had to kill some dashes and your answer helped...was just showing how it worked with dashes.

Answer (score 10):

I hate javascript replace since it always wants a regex. Try this

```
var $id=id.split("/").join("_");
```

Comment: Both from a performance and clarity-of-intent perspective, I cannot see how this is ever preferable.

Comment: @MattBall maybe when you have a dynamic separator and don't feel like escaping it to construct a RegExp object?

Comment: @MattBall In most languages, using replace lets you replace a string with a string, instead of needing a regex every time. the subject.split(search).join(replacement) construct is the closest thing in JS to a normal string replace. It is absurd that you should be required to use a regex everytime you want to do string replacement in JS.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the global flag which will do the replace function twice on your string, you can do this method which is a bit more specific and only replaces it once; it's also useful to know for other situations.

```
var $id = id.replace(/\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/, '_$1_$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function strReplace( str ) {
if( typeof str === 'string' ) {
    return text.replace( /[\/]/g, function( match, pos, originalText ) {
        if( match === '/' ){
            return '_';
        }
    });
}
return '';
}

console.log( strReplace( /Admin/ListOfMovies ) );
```