# I want to remove double quotes from a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the `""` around a String.

e.g. if the String is: `"I am here"` then I want to output only `I am here`.

Comment: Do you want to remove ALL the quotes or the boundary quotes?

Answer (score 582):

Assuming:

```
var someStr = 'He said "Hello, my name is Foo"';
console.log(someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```

That should do the trick... (if your goal is to replace *all* double quotes).

Here's how it works:

- `['"]` is a character class, matches both single and double quotes. you can replace this with `"` to only match double quotes.
- `+`: one or more quotes, chars, as defined by the preceding char-class (optional)
- `g`: the *global* flag. This tells JS to apply the regex to the entire string. If you omit this, you'll only replace a single char.

If you're trying to remove the quotes around a given string (ie in pairs), things get a bit trickier. You'll have to use lookaround assertions:

```
var str = 'remove "foo" delimiting double quotes';
console.log(str.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1'));
//logs remove foo delimiting quotes
str = 'remove only "foo" delimiting "';//note trailing " at the end
console.log(str.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1'));
//logs remove only foo delimiting "<-- trailing double quote is not removed
```

Regex explained:

- `"`: literal, matches any literal `"`
- `(`: begin capturing group. Whatever is between the parentheses (`()`) will be captured, and can be used in the replacement value.
- `[^"]+`: Character class, matches *all* chars, except `"` 1 or more times
- `(?=")`: zero-width (as in not captured) positive lookahead assertion. The previous match will only be valid if it's followed by a `"` literal
- `)`: end capturing group, we've captured everything in between the opening closing `"`
- `"`: another literal, cf list item one

The replacement is `'$1'`, this is a back-reference to the first captured group, being `[^" ]+`, or everyting in between the double quotes. The pattern matches both the quotes and what's inbetween them, but replaces it only with what's in between the quotes, thus effectively removing them.
What it does is `some "string with" quotes` -> replaces `"string with"` with -> `string with`. Quotes gone, job done.

If the quotes are *always* going to be at the begining and end of the string, then you could use this:

```
str.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1');
```

or this for double and single quotes:

```
str.replace(/^["'](.+(?=["']$))["']$/, '$1');
```

With input *`remove "foo" delimiting "`*, the output will remain unchanged, but change the input string to *`"remove "foo" delimiting quotes"`*, and you'll end up with `remove "foo" delimiting quotes` as output.

Explanation:

- `^"`: matches the beginning of the string `^` and a `"`. If the string does not start with a `"`, the expression already fails here, and nothing is replaced.
- `(.+(?="$))`: matches (and captures) everything, including double quotes one or more times, provided the positive lookahead is true
- `(?="$)`: the positive lookahead is much the same as above, only it specifies that the `"` *must* be the end of the string (`$` === end)
- `"$`: matches that ending quote, but does not capture it

The replacement is done in the same way as before: we replace the match (which includes the opening and closing quotes), with everything that was inside them. 
You may have noticed I've omitted the `g` flag (for global BTW), because since we're processing the entire string, this expression only applies once.
An easier regex that does, pretty much, the same thing (there are internal difference of how the regex is compiled/applied) would be:

```
someStr.replace(/^"(.+)"$/,'$1');
```

As before `^"` and `"$` match the delimiting quotes at the start and end of a string, and the `(.+)` matches everything in between, and captures it. I've tried this regex, along side the one above (with lookahead assertion) and, admittedly, to my surprize found this one to be slightly slower. My guess would be that the lookaround assertion causes the previous expression to fail as soon as the engine determines there is no `"` at the end of the string. Ah well, but if this is what you want/need, please *do read on*:

However, in this last case, it's far safer, faster, more maintainable and just better to do this:

```
if (str.charAt(0) === '"' && str.charAt(str.length -1) === '"')
{
    console.log(str.substr(1,str.length -2));
}
```

Here, I'm checking if the first and last char in the string are double quotes. If they are, I'm using `substr` to *cut off* those first and last chars. Strings are zero-indexed, so the last char is the `charAt(str.length -1)`. `substr` expects 2 arguments, where the first is the offset from which the substring starts, the second is its length. Since we don't want the last char, anymore than we want the first, that length is `str.length - 2`. Easy-peazy.

*Tips*:

More on lookaround assertions [can be found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
Regex's are very useful (and IMO fun), can be a bit baffeling at first. [Here's some more details, and links to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace/9514142#9514142) on the matter.
If you're not very comfortable using regex's just yet, you might want to consider using:

```
var noQuotes = someStr.split('"').join('');
```

If there's a lot of quotes in the string, this might even be faster than using regex

Comment: @rid: I edited, expainding a bit on what the expression does, and how to customize it

Comment: I think `someStr.replace(/^"(.+)"$/,'$1');` should use `.*` instead of `.+`. Test case `'""'`. For example `'""'.replace(/^"(.+)"$/,'$1')` return `""`, but `'""'.replace(/^"(.*)"$/,'$1')` returns ``

Comment: wouldnt `str.length -2` cut off the last character?

Comment: @MoralCode No, seeing as you're taking the substring starting at index 1 (of a zero-indexed string) and you want to exclude the last character, too. So `str.length` is the full length including the first and last character. The substring you're after starts at index 1, and has a total length of the original string -2. You can try with `x = "'remove single quotes'"; x.substr(1, x.length-2)`. Works like a charm

Answer (score 139):

```
str = str.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
```

This regexp will only remove the quotes if they are the first and last characters of the string. F.ex:

```
"I am here"  => I am here (replaced)
I "am" here  => I "am" here (untouched)
I am here"   => I am here" (untouched)
```

Answer (score 116):

If the string is guaranteed to have one quote (or any other single character) at beginning and end which you'd like to remove:

```
str = str.slice(1, -1);
```

`slice` has much less overhead than a regular expression.

Comment: Surprised this has been downvoted since it's exactly the kind of 'quick' operation you need if you're dealing with RDF literals (in N3, for example, URIs are usually denoted like `<uri>` and literals like `"literal"`). So here's an upvote. ;)

Comment: (Particularly because the original question says they want to remove the quotes *around* a string.)

Comment: It removes "" but also removes the characters from  the  both the ends

Comment: @Harshit It removes 1 character from each end. That is all. It doesn't matter what the characters are but for this question it is assumed that they are quotes.

Answer (score 56):

If you have control over your data and you know your double quotes surround the string (so do not appear inside string) and the string is an integer ... say with :

```
"20151212211647278"
```

or similar this nicely removes the surrounding quotes

```
JSON.parse("20151212211647278");
```

Not a universal answer however slick for niche needs

Comment: This will error on FireFox with: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: no ... works just fine on current fresh release of FireFox

Comment: JSON.parse("{123123}"); this will blow off your answer

Comment: `JSON.parse("20151212211647278dfvs");`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 17`

Comment: i got an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Syntax error with this as well; works kind of, but resolves in errors, hacky solution

Answer (score 21):

If you only want to remove the boundary quotes:

```
function stripquotes(a) {
    if (a.charAt(0) === '"' && a.charAt(a.length-1) === '"') {
        return a.substr(1, a.length-2);
    }
    return a;
}
```

This approach won't touch the string if it doesn't look like `"text in quotes"`.

Comment: Use `a.charAt(x)` if you want < ECMA5 support (f.ex IE7).

Comment: If someone receive deprecated error message, please use: `function stripquotes(a) {
  if (a.charAt(0) === '"' && a.charAt(a.length-1) === '"') {
      return a.substring(1, a.length-1);
  }
  return a;
}`

Answer (score 16):

A one liner for the lazy people

```
var str = '"a string"';
str = str.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer. `/"/g` won't work for `"My name is \"Jason\""`.

Comment: this answer removes *every* quote in the beginning and the end, which is not good in case of `" - is a quote` string, so it's not the same as *around*

Answer (score 11):

If you only want to remove quotes from the beginning or the end, use the following regular expression:

```
'"Hello"'.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
```

Comment: Note this would also alter `"foo` and `foo"`. One might only want to drop whole pairs of these.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I thought it was an expected behavior, though.

Comment: i think the parentheses are useless

Answer (score 5):

To restate your problem in a way that's easier to express as a regular expression:

> Get the substring of characters that is contained between zero or one leading double-quotes and zero or one trailing double-quotes.

Here's the regexp that does that:

```
  var regexp = /^"?(.+?)"?$/;
  var newStr = str.replace(/^"?(.+?)"?$/,'$1');
```

Breaking down the regexp:

- `^"?` a greedy match for zero or one leading double-quotes
- `"?$` a greedy match for zero or one trailing double-quotes
- those two bookend a non-greedy capture of all other characters, `(.+?)`, which will contain the target as `$1`.

This will return `delimited "string" here` for:

```
str = "delimited "string" here"  // ...
str = '"delimited "string" here"' // ...
str = 'delimited "string" here"' // ... and
str = '"delimited "string" here'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use replaceAll

```
const someStr = 'He said "Hello, my name is Foo"';

console.log(someStr.replaceAll('"', '')); 

// => 'He said Hello, my name is Foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all double quotes in string, use

```
var str = '"some "quoted" string"';
console.log( str.replace(/"/g, '') );
// some quoted string
```

Otherwise you want to remove only quotes around the string, use:

```
var str = '"some "quoted" string"';
console.log( clean = str.replace(/^"|"$/g, '') );
// some "quoted" string
```

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```js
var string1 = "'foo'";
var string2 = '"bar"';

function removeFirstAndLastQuotes(str){
  var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
  var lastChar = str[str.length -1];
  //double quotes
  if(firstChar && lastChar === String.fromCharCode(34)){
    str = str.slice(1, -1);
  }
  //single quotes
  if(firstChar && lastChar === String.fromCharCode(39)){
    str = str.slice(1, -1);
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(removeFirstAndLastQuotes(string1));
console.log(removeFirstAndLastQuotes(string2));
```

Comment: code is wrong. Try empty string input, or try `'foo"` or simply `foo"`

Comment: The `if(firstChar && lastChar === String.fromCharCode(34))` is wrong, you can't compare two strings in one go like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var expressionWithoutQuotes = '';
for(var i =0; i<length;i++){
    if(expressionDiv.charAt(i) != '"'){
        expressionWithoutQuotes += expressionDiv.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

This may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove the double quotes try following

```
  var Stringstr = "\"I am here\"";
  var mystring = String(Stringstr);
  mystring = mystring.substring(1, mystring.length - 1);
  alert(mystring);
```

Comment: if I have a multidimensional array each value have prefix & post fix double quats then how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the code to remove a Single (or more) double quote character(s) from a Batch variable (based on a combination of everyone else's good work).

```
set test=SomeInputString with one " or more "characters" inside the string

:SINGLEDoubleQUOTERemover
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET test=!test:"=!
::If the variable/input is empty to start with you must run the command twice...
SET test=!test:"=!
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
ECHO %test%
::If the input is empty it ends up with a single = in the variable
IF "%test%"=="=" GOTO :EXIT
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34518629)

Comment: Sorry but the OP's question refers to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will also work, to remove for example double quote from a string surrounded with double quote:

```
var str = 'remove "foo" delimiting double quotes';
console.log(str.replace(/"(.+)"/g, '$1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is very better for show number in textbox

$(this) = [your textbox]

```
            var number = $(this).val();
            number = number.replace(/[',]+/g, '');
            number = number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
            $(this).val(number); // "1,234,567,890"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be old school, go with REGEX 1,$s/"//g

Comment: Question is about JavaScript.

Answer (score -9):

Please try following regex for remove double quotes from string .

```
    $string = "I am here";
    $string =~ tr/"//d;
    print $string;
    exit();
```

Comment: They want a javascript solution!