# How to avoid single quotes in sequelize query with replacements?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to do a raw query using Sequelize and use replacements to avoid sql injection:

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM table where name =:name ORDER BY :age:direction",
{replacements:{name:"test", age:"age", direction:"desc"}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

This will be converted to following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE name = 'test' 
ORDER BY 'age' 'desc'
```

Since the order by column is having single quotes and direction also with single quotes, postgres throws error

Can anyone suggest how do I solve this problem with replacements in place?

Comment: IMHO, age and desc shouldn't be parameters but part of the raw query:
"SELECT * FROM table where name =:name ORDER BY age desc"

Comment: the order by column is dynamic so it will be part of replacements. we dont want it to be parameters.

Comment: @Manu I have a similar issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done with replacements because they only support values, not syntactic elements of the SQL language (such as `DESC`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using replacements with a raw Sequelize query: avoiding single quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092913/using-replacements-with-a-raw-sequelize-query-avoiding-single-quotes)

Comment: i am facing same problem, @Manu have you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I created the query and the sort order by separately and then concatenate them as follow:

```
const query= `SELECT * FROM table where name =:name ORDER BY :age`;
let sortOrder = `DESC`
sequelize.query(`${query} ${sortOrder}`, {replacements:{name:"test", age:"age"}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

being there is just about play with the `sortORder`