# How to remove unwanted character from string in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do a bit of cleaning up on some data that I have imported from a csv file. I figured out how to get the formatting for some of the columns how I need it but am struggling with the double quotes that remain on either end of each row. I assume the quotes are being added as a result of the `getDataAsString()` function.

As you can see from the below I am trying to use `replace()` to get rid of the double quote from the values in the last column. The logger shows the data without the `"`, but the line I have used is not having any effect on the data in the sheet. I suspect this is because all I am doing with the script that I have so far, is saying "show me the value from the last column without the quote" but not actually updating the data.

How can I convert the "show" line to an actual change data line?

```js
function importFromCSV() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(listLatestFile());
  //var csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
  var csvFile = file.getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();
  //Logger.log(csvFile);// check in the logger
  var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile);// convert to 2D array
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ImpCSVData");
      sheet.clear();
      sheet.getRange(1,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step
      var test = sheet.getRange(1,csvData[0].length, csvData.length, 1).getValue().replace("\"","");
      Logger.log(test);
      sheet.getRange(1,4, csvData.length, 2).setNumberFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
      sheet.getRange(1,6, csvData.length, 1).setNumberFormat("@STRING@");
      sheet.getRange(1,csvData[0].length, csvData.length, 1).getValue().replace("\"","");
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...the line I have used is not having any effect on the data in the sheet

In the code snippet you've provided, there is no `setValue()` or `setValues()` call being made. Without that, you aren't making any changes to the content of the spreadsheet. Say you have a variable, `text`, that you want to write to the sheet. You should then do this:

```
  sheet.getRange(1,csvData[0].length, csvData.length, 1).setValue(text);
```

The `.getValue()` method returns an object from the given range - your code assumes this is a string. If it isn't a string (say it's a date or number instead), then `.replace()` will throw an exception. Even if it is a string, this line will do nothing of use because you aren't storing the result in any way:

```
  sheet.getRange(1,csvData[0].length, csvData.length, 1).getValue().replace("\"","");
```

Try:

```
  var lastCellRange = sheet.getRange(1,csvData[0].length, csvData.length, 1);
  var text = lastCellRange.getValue().replace("\"","");
  lastCellRange.setValue(text);
```

Other comments:

- Your `replace()` statement will change the first occurrence of the double-quote character, regardless of where it appears. You want to replace leading or trailing quotes which may or may not be there, so try this instead (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26160431/1677912)):

  `var text = lastCellRange.getValue().replace(/^"?(.+?)"?$/,'$1');`