# Double quotes in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, escaping

Im coding a Chrome extension and tried injecting some code like this:

```
var actualCode = ['$("a").unbind("click");'].join('\n');

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

I have the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)

The problem is that I have to use double quotes which relates to a right click from the context menu, so the code become:

```
 Injecting-Code: "var actualCode = ['$("a").unbind("click");'].join('\n');"
```

How do I handle the double quotes in my Jquery: `$("a").unbind("click");`

**Note : I tried escaping them like this \" but it doesnt work**

Comment: Where does this `Injecting-Code` message come from? Looks like it's just the output there that is not properly escaped.

Comment: Injecting-Code is part of a function which I need to inject the code into website

Comment: Please show us that function. `console.log` for example is known to not escape anything in a string, but just place quotes around it.

Comment: @Bergi Im at work and I have the code home...sorry, but its just a simple function nothing fancy. I really think the double quotes are the problem, because the error messages from console where pointing to the beginning of double quotes

Answer (score -1):

`['$("a").unbind("click");'].join('\n')` this technique is used when you have multiple lines of code.

you better use this
`var actualCode = '$("a").unbind("click");';`

This should solve your problem. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Please look at this code:  `Injecting-Code: "var actualCode = ['$("a").unbind("click");'].join('\n');"` There are too many double quotes, that is the problem

Comment: where `Injecting-Code:` comes from?

Comment: Hi that is a function in a special script. The function does the actual injection, I need it like that.

Comment: You mean you passing `actualCode` as string parameter to `Injecting-Code` function?

Comment: Yes exactly like a string

Comment: Then you strip `"` in `Injecting-Code` method before actually injecting.

Comment: I dont get it..can you please elaborate?

Comment: Show us implementation of your `Injecting-Code` method.

Comment: Like I told Bergi Im at work and I dont have the code/script her, sorry. But it shouldnt matter its just a simple function

Comment: okay go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string here and check David's answer.

Comment: Will give it a try, thank you very much. I want to vote up but dont have credit..

Comment: Np... Let us know if yo still have a problem