# How to take the string value out of its scope(unstring)?

Tags: javascript

I have looked through string methods, but couldn't find any method to throw the string value out of its scope. Is there any function to unString the string in JavaScript? 
For instance if I receive a calculation in a string form from another file:

```
var five = 5
var three = 3
var calculation = five * three;
var string = 'calculation * 1232123 - five + three';
```

How can I store that received string in a variable where those values get out of string scope and get calculated? Is there a way or is there a method to do so?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `eval`, but you really shouldn't use that. Where do you get that `string` from?

Comment: [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "string scope".

Comment: from another js file but I the value of option element which returns string

Comment: use cookie or storage

Comment: @developer You really should link the option to a function that you can call, not to a string.

Comment: if he able to call at times means he can use cookies or web storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` function. But remember, that `eval` is `evil`.

Comment: Yes, it's evil. Can you suggest a better alternative?

Comment: A better alternative is to make `Code refactoring`, so that there will be no reason to use `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe eval() is what you are looking for? Eval "parses" the string and runs whatever text is there (or evaluates i guess)

```
var five = 5
eval("five + five")
```

This outputs 10 if you run it. Take note! This will solve the specific question you ask, but its probably not a good way to solve your actual problem (that we dont know much about)

Comment: Yup. Provided the string is from a *trusted source*, using `eval` is perfectly fine and the most direct way to address the OP's question given the level of detail we have. From an *untrusted source*, they'd have to write an expression parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template string and `JSON.parse`

```
var five = 5;
var three = 3;
var calculation = five * three;
var string = `${calculation * 1232123 - five + three}`;
JSON.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sentence like this:

```
let str= "Hello World"
```

and you want to unstring the value or remove quotes from it, you can do something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g,"")
```

Now value of `str` is `Hello World`

Comment: If you want more details, visit this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string/34245366