# JavaScript Object remove quotes in specific key value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove double quotes for specific key value:

```
upload: {
    name: "upload",
    url: "/upload",
    controller: "invoicesCtrl",
    templateUrl: "./views/invoices.html",
    resolve: "resolveUrl('./compiled/invoices_app.js')"
  },
  invoices: {
    name: "invoices",
    url: "/invoices",
    controller: "invoicesCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/invoices/views/invoices.html",
    resolve: "resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')"
  }
```

Just for resolve key values, the others have to be strings. Is there any regular expression for this with the `replace` function? The expected result:

```
upload: {
    name: "upload",
    url: "/upload",
    controller: "invoicesCtrl",
    templateUrl: "./views/invoices.html",
    resolve: resolveUrl('./compiled/invoices_app.js')
  },
  invoices: {
    name: "invoices",
    url: "/invoices",
    controller: "invoicesCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/invoices/views/invoices.html",
    resolve: resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')
  }
```

Comment: Assuming you are using JavaScript, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string.

Comment: @SeanPerkins thats not what I expected

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to assign `resolve` the result of running `eval` on the current value of `resolve`?

Comment: Side note, that's just a JavaScript object, not JSON. I've edited your title to reflect this and removed the `json` tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're saying *remove double quotes* and the only double quoes in `resolve` are the string literal terminators, are you saying you want a JavaScript function called `resolveUrl` to be called at some point, and that `resolve` should be the result of that call?

In that case, you could do something like:

```
// iterate through all properties of myObject, assuming it is a flat
// object containing upload and invoices from your code
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {

   if(myObject[key].hasOwnProperty('resolve'))
      myObject[key].resolve = eval(myObject[key].resolve);

});
```

If you know that it will always be a `resolveUrl` call, it'd be more safe to just let the original property contain the string value - eg. `resolve: '/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js'` - and then call `resolveUrl` manually:

```
if(myObject[key].hasOwnProperty('resolve'))
   myObject[key].resolve = resolveUrl(myObject[key].resolve);
```