# Why angularjs error response prints the laravel error with square bracket and double quote?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to print the laravel error through angularjs, i have done but there is problem inside the code. Script is also showing square bracket and double quote.

**Validation in Controller**

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
]);
```

**In AngularJs**

```
request.error(function (error) {
    $scope.mError = error.email;
    $scope.loader=false;
});
```

**In HTML**

```
<div class="err" ng-if="mError">@{{ mError }}</div>

**OutPut**
["The email must be a valid email address."]
```

Can anyone guide me how can i prevent to print the double quotes and square brackets with error? I would like to appreciate. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str.charAt(0) === '[' && str.charAt(1) === '"'&& str.charAt(str.length -2) === '"' && str.charAt(str.length -1) === '"')
 {
     console.log(str.substr(2,str.length -3));
  }
```

Also read this helps you

[I want to remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string)