# Set parameters in URL dynamically Angularjs2

Tags: angular

I need to set some values dynamically in a URL.
The code i have now

```
export class AccountService {

private accounts;
private URL="";

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.URL =   "http://payd.azurewebsites.net/api/User/"+localStorage.getItem("paydid")+"/accou nt";
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("paydid"));
}

httpGet(): Observable<Account> {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  return this.http.get(this.URL, {
    headers: headers
  }).catch((error: any, caught: Observable<any>) => {
      return Observable.throw(error);
    })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

Im trying to set the value like this in url `this.URL = "http://payd.azurewebsites.net/api/User/"+localStorage.getItem("paydid")+"/account"`. But this gives me something like this `http://payd.azurewebsites.net/api/User/%221%22/account`. In `console.log()` it show the correct value of `localStorage.getItem("paydid")`. How to do this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: `%221%22` is urlencoded `"1"`. You should strip the quotes after you get it from storage

Comment: @peeskillet; thanks for replying. could you please guide me with some code since im not clear what to do.

Comment: [here are some options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19156148/2587435). Strip the quotes from the value returned from `localStorage.getItem("paydid")`

Comment: @peeskillet; Thanks alot. Yes now it is working.