# How to remove quotes from around a string in Golang

Tags: go

I have a string in Golang that is surrounded by quote marks. My goal is to remove all quote marks on the sides, but to ignore all quote marks in the interior of the string. How should I go about doing this? My instinct tells me to use a RemoveAt function like in C#, but I don't see anything like that in Go.

For instance:

```
"hello""world"
```

should be converted to:

```
hello""world
```

For further clarification, this:

```
"""hello"""
```

would become this:

```
""hello""
```

because the outer ones should be removed ONLY.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

```
s = s[1 : len(s)-1]
```

If there's a possibility that the quotes are not present, then use this:

```
if len(s) > 0 && s[0] == '"' {
    s = s[1:]
}
if len(s) > 0 && s[len(s)-1] == '"' {
    s = s[:len(s)-1]
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/x_DG9vHvzY)

Comment: Why do `len(s)` twice? Why not nest it like so?: `if len(s) { if s[0] == '"' { s = s[1:] } if s[len(s)-1] == '"' { s = s[:len(s)-1] } }`

Comment: @apokaliptis  The answer checks len(s) twice to handle the input `"`.

Comment: I tried both these approcehes for rederning a string in a html template and in both ceases they removed the result still had the quote in it; i.e. <p>"his is the string with quotes yet missing the first and last characte"</p>

Comment: @AlanCarlyle: It looks like (a) you used first approach that removes the first and last byte from the string, no matter what those bytes are (b) the template is adding quotes.  You should ask a new question if you have not figured out what's wrong with your program.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm fairly sure the go html/template is adding the quotes itself as I know I'm not doing putting them in the sting. I've had a hunt for answers to the problem and most have just dealt with how to escape quotes in html so the display.

Answer (score 13):

`strings.Trim()` can be used to remove the leading and trailing whitespace from a string. It won't work if the double quotes are in between the string.

```
// strings.Trim() will remove all the occurrences from the left and right

s := `"""hello"""`
fmt.Println("Before Trim: " + s)                    // Before Trim: """hello"""
fmt.Println("After Trim: " + strings.Trim(s, "\"")) // After Trim: hello

// strings.Trim() will not remove any occurrences from inside the actual string

s2 := `""Hello" " " "World""`
fmt.Println("\nBefore Trim: " + s2)                  // Before Trim: ""Hello" " " "World""
fmt.Println("After Trim: " + strings.Trim(s2, "\"")) // After Trim: Hello" " " "World
```

Playground link - https://go.dev/play/p/yLdrWH-1jCE

Comment: `Trim` is handy if I know the format of the input string.

Comment: This would trim multiple quotes at the beginning and end, correct? The author only wants to trim one set of quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Use [slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions). You should write robust code that provides correct output for imperfect input. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trimQuotes(s string) string {
    if len(s) >= 2 {
        if s[0] == '"' && s[len(s)-1] == '"' {
            return s[1 : len(s)-1]
        }
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    tests := []string{
        `"hello""world"`,
        `"""hello"""`,
        `"`,
        `""`,
        `"""`,
        `goodbye"`,
        `"goodbye"`,
        `goodbye"`,
        `good"bye`,
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("`%s` -> `%s`\n", test, trimQuotes(test))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
`"hello""world"` -> `hello""world`
`"""hello"""` -> `""hello""`
`"` -> `"`
`""` -> ``
`"""` -> `"`
`goodbye"` -> `goodbye"`
`"goodbye"` -> `goodbye`
`goodbye"` -> `goodbye"`
`good"bye` -> `good"bye`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of slices to remove the first and last element of the slice.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := `"hello""world"`

    if str[0] == '"' {
        str = str[1:]
    }
    if i := len(str)-1; str[i] == '"' {
        str = str[:i]
    }

    fmt.Println( str )
}
```

Since a slice shares the underlying memory, this does not copy the string. It just changes the `str` slice to start one character over, and end one character sooner.

This is how [the various bytes.Trim functions](https://golang.org/src/bytes/bytes.go) work.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks, I'm still learning the relationship between string and []byte. I had a page that explained when a copy would happen and when it wouldn't, but I've misplaced it. Do you have a resource?

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using regular expressions...

```
quoted = regexp.MustCompile(`^"(.*)"$`).ReplaceAllString(quoted,`$1`)
```

But it doesn't necessarily handle escaped quotes they way you might want.

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vqtzieLdt3H)

*Translated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156525/86967).*