# Remove quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting data in a variable as `""Value""`. So, I want to remove  quotes but only inner quotes.
I tried with this but it's not working.

```
var value = "fetchedValue";
value = value.replace(/\"/g, "");
```

Can anyone explain with an example?

```
expected = "Value"
```

Comment: Your current `value` has no quotes in the variable - it's a string. Did you mean `var value = '"fetchedValue"';`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string)

Comment: Your example `var value = "fetchedValue"; value = value.replace(/\"/g, "");` makes no sense. There are no double quote characters in the 'value' variable initially. Also, what *specific* issue are you getting. Saying it's "not working" isn't helpful, describe how it isn't working and any console (or other) errors you're getting

Comment: @CertainPerformance  No I was getting data as ""FetchedValue"" but now it's working fine for me with value = value.replace(/\"/g, "");

Comment: Please provide an example that actually demonstrates the behaviour you're experiencing. Your `value` does **not** have any quotes in it, so people cannot help you correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's weird. Your solution should work.
 Well, try this:

```
var value = "fetchedValue";
value = value.slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: Short and simple

Answer (score 9):

I hope this will work:

```
var value = '"fetchedValue"';
value = value.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = '"Value"';
str = str.replace(/"|'/g, '');
```

**output = Value**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will take care about existing of two quotes `""`

```js
function removeQuotes(a) {
    var fIndex = a.indexOf('""');
    var lIndex = a.lastIndexOf('""');
    if(fIndex >= 0 && lIndex >= 0){
      a = a.substring(fIndex+1, lIndex+1);
    }
    return a;
    
}

console.log(removeQuotes('"Foo Bar"'));
console.log(removeQuotes('""Foo Bar""'));
```