# Regex Remove pair of double quotes around word, but not single instances of double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes

I need to be able to **remove a pair of double quotes around words**, **without removing single instances of double quotes.**

Ie. in the below examples, the regex should only match around "hello" and "bounce", without removing the word itself.

---

3.5" hdd

"hello"

"cool

"bounce"

single sentence with out quotes.

---

Closest regex i've found so far is this one below, but this highlights the entire "bounce" word which is not acceptable as I need to retain the word.

```
"([^\\"]|\\")*"
```

Other close regex I've found in my research:

1.

```
\"*\"
```

but this highlights the single quotes.

and [Unsuccessful Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string)

This needs to be usable in C# code.

I've been using RegexStorm to test my regex: http://regexstorm.net/reference

Comment: First regex seems fine but it lacks an outer capturing group: `"((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)"` after matching you should replace with a back-reference to first capturing group `\1`. Check this live demo https://regex101.com/r/FWUQdB/1

Comment: Perfect thank you, I can accept if you post as an answer.

Comment: How is this properly escaped in c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first regex seems fine but lacks an outer capturing group. It would be better if we transform this into a linear regex, avoiding alternation.

```
"([^\\"\r\n]*(?:\\.[^\\"\r\n]*)*)"
```

I included carriage return `\r` and `\n` in character class to prevent regex from going more than one line in regex, you may not need them however. You then replace whole match with `$1` (a back-reference to first capturing group saved data). To escape a `"` in C# use double quote `""`.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/q624UH/1)

C# code:

```
string pattern = @"""([^\\""\r\n]*(?:\\.[^\\""\r\n]*)*)""";
string input = @"3.5"" hdd
    ""hello""
    ""cool
    ""bounce""
    single sentence with out quotes.";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, @"$1"));
```

Comment: Thanks, due to the nature of the character i was trying to find, wasn't sure if using the regular c# escape character would affect it or not.