# Why clicking link in Qt app causes Windows 10 popup "You'll need a new app to open this qrc link"?

Tags: qt, qml, markdown

I'm using a Qt 5.14 QML `Text` component with the following code:

```
Text {
    text: reader.content
    onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(link)
}
```

When I click a markdown link displayed in the Text component, a popup appears:

[image: Windows 10 error popup displaying "You'll need a new app to open this qrc link", a button labeled "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store", a checked box labeled "Always use this app" and a disabled OK button]

I really don't like the options; I cannot click OK to continue and I don't want to go to the Microsoft store.

Here's an example of link text that produces this behavior:

```
[bad link]("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is surrounded by quotes. [Removing the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string) fixes the problem:

```
Text {
    text: reader.content
    onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(link.replace(/['"]+/g, ''))
}
```

Comment: I think Windows determined it's a Qt app and assumed it was opening an embedded resource, hence the "qrc" description of the link. 

I got zero hits when looking for the exact error message.

Comment: Certainly not. It's rather that the quotes are wrong, so My guess would be that Qt gets confused by the quotes, doesn't recognise the string as URL, and assumes a (relative) path, which is completed to a qrc URL