# how I can remove quote marks from stringified array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, slice

So after `JSON.stringify` an array with object,

I have this result `[{"title":"Unavaible","start":"2020-05-19","end":"2020-05-22"}]`.

But the title, start, end I would like them without with the `" "` anyone knows how I can remove them somehow?

Comment: Is there a way that you could give more background to this task? Where is that file being saved? If saved in a json file, that's a valid key, you can't just remove the double quotation. Please explain more about your situation.

Comment: by default JSON.stringify convert your object to string that contain keys and values, use  JSON.parse to convert stringify to original object

Comment: What would you want to do that?

Comment: @RenanCidale you CAN just remove then double quotation...

Comment: of course you can, you can go and delete manually the key, you can use search and replace in your IDE, you can run .replace if that's a string. But not knowing to what purpose that's being used, everything get's lost. JSON without double quotation is not a valid JSON anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it because that is the proper format of JSON, but I found some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156197/8540492) which will do it.

```js
var someStr = 'He said "Hello, my name is Foo"';
console.log(someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```