# JavaScript to pull CSV and styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a javascript that reads a CSV file.
I can run this code successfully and get the CSV file data imported in a div. However, there are six columns in CSV file. I only need to get column 1 and column 3 from CSV file and display in div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Upload() {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = document.createElement("table");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var cells = rows[i].split(","); if (cells.length > 1) {
                            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                            for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                                cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                    dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                    dvCSV.appendChild(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    }
```

Load Summary File

I got another code from another website that reads through "table" but seems function is not able to recognize "table" element:

```
<script>
function showTableData() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
    var myTab = document.getElementById('table');

    // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
    for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
        
        // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
        var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
        for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
            info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
            
            var thisitem = objCells.item(j).innerHTML
            if (thisitem == "01") {
                alert(thisitem);
                objCells.item(j).style.color = "red";
            }            
        }
        
        info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + '<br />';     // ADD A BREAK (TAG).
        
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. How do I apply a class to dynamically created Table?
2. How do I check column1 and column3 data and then change the style.

My biggest frustration is that I am not able to access "Table" element that was created dynamically.

Thank You
Nratawa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to access table:**

To access the table, you need to make sure the table has an [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) of `table` due to this line of code `var myTab = document.getElementById('table');`. The solution for this is setting the id on the table created like so:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id = 'table' // now document.getElementById('table') works because the table has matching id
```

**How to add class to table:**

To add a class to the dynamically created table, you can use the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) api.

Example:
`table.classList.add('tableClass')`

**How to only collect columns 1 and 3:**

If you only want columns 1 and 3, you can use a combo of an array and `continue` in the cells loop

```
function Upload() {
    const columns = [0, 2] // represents allowed column 1 and 3 in index form

    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var table = document.createElement("table");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var cells = rows[i].split(","); if (cells.length > 1) {
                        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            // ignore columns that are not allowed
                            if (!columns.includes(j)) {
                              continue
                            }

                            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                            cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                dvCSV.appendChild(table);
            }
            reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It has worked great. However, the returned output from CSV shows double quotes symbol around value. For example it shows "Dave". I would only like to show Dave.

Comment: There are a few ways to do that using String api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

One simple way is with the `String.replace` method and regex although note that this strips ALL double quotes, not just the ones at start and end.

`cell.innerHTML = cells[j].replace(/"/g, '');`.

Reference this StackOverflow question for a more in depth solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!