# Importing script name from SQL to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql, scripting, nodes

I'm attempting to import an external script into an HTML file. The name of the js file that I want to import is hosted in a SQL database. Therefore, I am using a XMLHttpRequest to access the SQL database so that I can fetch the appropriate name of the script. I then create a script element where I set src equal to 'this.responseText' which should import the name taken from the SQL database. So far so good. My issue is that when I console.log out the script it double wraps the name in qouteationmarks like so:

```
console: 

 <script src=""haystack_downtheline""></script>
```

How do I remove the double quotes so that src="haystack_downtheline".

See below for entire script

```
HTML file     
<script>


    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // New request object
    oReq.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        const js = document.createElement("script");
        js.src = this.responseText;
        console.log(js);

    };



    oReq.open("get", "index.php", true);
    oReq.send();



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer work?

[I want to remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string)

I personally would use this, since I don't find regex readable:

```
var noQuotes = this.responseText.split('"').join('');
```