# I want to remove the '' around a String need to get CKEDITOR value CKEDITOR.instances.editor_1003.getData() and id name equal to editor_1003

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to remove the '' around a String.

e.g. if the String is: 'editor_1003' then I want to output only editor_1003.
because I am using multiple CKEditor and I want to get data this type this is coming as string i am getting error

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor_1003.getData();

Answer is 
CKEDITOR.instances["editor_1003"].getData();
```

Comment: does this answer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string/19156197

Answer (score 2):

To remove leading/trailing single quote you may use:

```js
var input = "'editor_1003'";
console.log(input);
var output = input.replace(/^'|'$/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @NeerajKumar Typo...I needed a global replace.  Try the updated version.

Comment: thanks man i got a solutions
"CKEDITOR.instances[editor_id_name].getData();"

Comment: sorry I didn't understand please you want to say correct your answer?

Comment: The answer is working, check the demo.

Comment: actually correct way to implementing this way "CKEDITOR.instances["editor_1003"].getData();" 
previously i am trying this things 
CKEDITOR.instances.editor_1003.getData(); 
your answer is also correct . thanks for replay i will do green tab 

Comment: i am accepting you Answer please remove negative response if possible