# Get specific value from OData response in Postman

Tags: postman, odata

Can anyone of you can help me this:
i Have such response body from WebAPI:

```
{
    "value": "Created: \"salesorder\" : \"22a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958\"
Found 0 vis1_anschlussadresses
Found 1 vis1_postleitzahls
Reusing: \"vis1_postleitzahl\" : \"0d9344c7-a45d-e711-80c5-955c5ca2a164\"
Found 1 vis1_orts
Reusing: \"vis1_ort\" : \"92734f57-375e-e711-80c5-955c5ca2a164\"
Created: \"vis1_anschlussadresse\" : \"67a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958\"
Found 0 vis1_anschlussobjekts
Created: \"vis1_anschlussobjekt\" : \"6ba734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958\"
Found 0 vis1_infrastrukturinformations
Created: \"vis1_infrastrukturinformation\" : \"6fa734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958\"
Found 1 contacts
Reusing: \"contact\" : \"22530f60-285f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958\"
Found 1 competitors
Reusing: \"competitor\" : \"7841f8e7-c211-ea11-80cd-0050568d3968\"
[0000]: Information: OK
"
}
```

i'd like to get specific values from this response body e.g. 22a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958 and store as a environment variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Deserialize it and get the value

Comment: You mean as a Postman environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

The first observation is that the response is a standard serialized structure. Even if we deserialise the JSON payload, the *value* of `value` is this string, that seems to represent a form of execution log:

```
Created: "salesorder" : "22a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958"
Found 0 vis1_anschlussadresses
Found 1 vis1_postleitzahls
Reusing: "vis1_postleitzahl" : "0d9344c7-a45d-e711-80c5-955c5ca2a164"
Found 1 vis1_orts
Reusing: "vis1_ort" : "92734f57-375e-e711-80c5-955c5ca2a164"
Created: "vis1_anschlussadresse" : "67a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958"
Found 0 vis1_anschlussobjekts
Created: "vis1_anschlussobjekt" : "6ba734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958"
Found 0 vis1_infrastrukturinformations
Created: "vis1_infrastrukturinformation" : "6fa734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958"
Found 1 contacts
Reusing: "contact" : "22530f60-285f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958"
Found 1 competitors
Reusing: "competitor" : "7841f8e7-c211-ea11-80cd-0050568d3968"
[0000]: Information: OK
```

To specifically resolve the value `22a734c3-bf5f-ec11-80e6-0050568d2958` we need to make a few assumtions:

1. the value we are looking for is in the *First* line
2. the value is contained inside double quotes
3. the quoted value is the entire line content after the *last* full-colon character `;`
4. the name of the environment variable is `FirstGuid`

Given those assumptions, we can write a *Tests* script to run after the request:

```js
var logValue = pm.response.json().value;
var lines = logValue.split(/\r?\n/);
var lineOneTokens = lines[0].split(':');
var guid = lineOneTokens[lineOneTokens.length() - 1].trim().replace(/"/g,"");

pm.environment.set('FirstGuid', guid);
```

References:

- [Scripting in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/)
- [JavaScript - split string by new line character](https://dirask.com/posts/JavaScript-split-string-by-new-line-character-k1wEQp)
- [How to Get the Last Element of an Array in JavaScript](https://actualwizard.com/javascript-last-element-in-array)
- [I want to remove double quotes from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19156148/1690217)