# Replace All Same String Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I want to Replace `2013-2-2` to `2013,2,2`

I tried

```
var forrep = '2013-2-2'; 

var text = forrep.replace('-', ',');
```

but it only replaces the first `-` the output looks like this `2013,2-2`

I want all the `-` to be replaced by `,` commna

Please help Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multiple replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression with the `/g` switch to make it match "globally":

```
var text = forrep.replace(/-/g, ',');
```